# How do I end the inner part of this nested loop but have the larger overall nested loop continue?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, minimax

I'm working on a part of a minimax AI for a Connect Four board.

I have a parallel gameboard to test that looks like this:

```
let parallelBoard = [
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
[15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
[22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
[29,30,31,32,33,34,35],
[36,37,38,39,40,41,42]
];
```

The `findAvailableSpots(board)` function gives me an array consisting of the numbers in the first row that are still available for play. I use the first row to determine this because I splice "Red" or "Yellow" into the array whenever a spot is taken, and if the first row for that column is occupied, it cannot be selected anymore.

Then I loop through the length of available spots, and take each one as the index of the column I want to put a marker into and test.

Next, for each one of these available spots, I loop upwards from the bottom or sixth row to place the token where there is no "red" or "yellow" string in that spot.

I would like it to stop once it finds a spot and move on to the next number in the `parallelAvailable` array.

But if I don't put in a return, it puts a token in every row of that column.

If I do put in a return, it `breaks` after splicing `[parallelAvailable][0]`.

I would like it to run the `i` loop to see which row it can put a token into, and then move on to the next in `[parallelAvailable][s]`.

What should I do? Am I placing the `return` in the wrong place, or is there a better way to do this altogether, maybe with another `if` condition?

```
function pickBestMove() {
//     let bestScore
//     let bestColumn

 let parallelAvailable = findAvailableSpots(parallelBoard)
 console.log(parallelAvailable)

 for (s=0; s<parallelAvailable.length; s++) {
    let i;
    let j = parseInt(parallelAvailable[s] - 1)
    console.log(j)
    for (i = 5; i > -1; i--) 
        {if (Number.isInteger(parallelBoard[i][j])) {
            parallelBoard[i].splice((j), 1, currentPlayer)
            }

    //         let positionScore = scorePosition (parallelBoard, currentPlayer)
    //         console.log(gameboard[i][j] + " gets " + positionScore)
    //         parallelBoard[i].splice((indexPick), 1, gameboard[i][j])
            
    //             if (positionScore > bestScore) {
    //                 bestScore = score
    //                 console.log(bestScore)
    //                 bestColumn = s
    //                 console.log(bestColumn)
    //             }
    //         // return
    //        }
    //     }
    }
    // return bestColumn
    console.log(parallelBoard)}
};
```

Comment: Use `break` https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: oh, that seemed to work! thank you. So easy! I feel dumb now having spent much more time putting together this question!